# Can I search for entries that have *only* certain values in a multi-valued attribute?

Tags: ldap

Let's say an LDAP schema has an attribute called "Food", which stores people's favorite foods.  It's a multi-valued attribute so there can be many different values listed for one person.

A partial dump of such an entry might look like this:

```
dn: cn=joe,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com
cn: joe
Food: pizza
Food: beer
Food: wings
```

So we can see that Joe really likes pizza, beer and wings.

Then let's say I want to match Joe up with other users who also enjoy pizza, beer and/or wings but not users who enjoy, say, brussels sprouts or cauliflower.

Is there a search filter that returns entries with one or more of "pizza", "beer" and "wings" -- **and nothing else** -- in the Food attribute?

The first part, looking for any or all of those three values, is easy:

```
(|(Food=pizza)(Food=beer)(Food=wings))
```

But how do I tell it to exclude entries which have any values other than those three?

Obviously I can post-process the search results and manually throw out any entries that have bad values, but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

If the "any values other than those three" are known and limited, you might be looking for something like this:

```
(&(|(Food=pizza)(Food=beer)(Food=wings))(|(!(Food=cauliflower))(!(Food=sprouts))))
```

Basically, you make a compound filter that says "It's pizza OR beer OR wings OR any combination of those, AND it's not cauliflower OR sprouts."

I'm not sure if there's a great way to say, "It's ONLY pizza OR beer OR wings OR any combination of those." The best way I can imagine involves creating an extremely verbose filter with all possible values in it. Maybe someone else knows a better way?

Comment: I was just using sprouts and cauliflower as silly examples; I did not mean to imply that the nonconforming values are known ahead of time.  I want to exclude entries which contain any foods other than "pizza", "beer" or "wings", whatever those foods may be.

Comment: Good to know. In that case, I have to recommend geoffc's approach below, experimentally. I don't have a handy LDAP to test this on, but his filter looks like it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Would negating this filter work?

`(&(!(Food=pizza))(!(Food=beer))(!(Food=wings))`

So that you get `(!(&(!(Food=pizza))(!(Food=beer))(!(Food=wings)))`

I doubt that is in any way efficient.  Not sure if it would work either...